# Maintaining line breaks in flash TLF editable field

Tags: php, flash, text-formatting

I have a TLF editable field in a swf file.  Text entered there gets sent to a php page where everything is processed.  I had the behavior set for `multiline`, but just realized that if someone hits return and keeps typing, no break is displayed (not even a space).

I've tried using `nl2br()` in the php when it grabs the POST variable from flash, but that doesn't work.

I don't know how flash handles the carriage return, so I don't know how to handle it on the php side either.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) function.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.